# How to add go.Figure into dash plotly layout in dash core component

Tags: python, django, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm new in dash plotly and I need to add go.Figure into app.layout
but I cant get correct result there is something wrong [image]

my code :

```
trace = go.Scatter(
    x=x1,
    y=y1,
    name="Completed",
    line_color='green'
)

layout = dict(
    title='Simple Graph',
    xaxis=dict(range=[min(x1) - datetime.timedelta(hours=2), max(x1)]),
    yaxis=dict(range=[0, max(max(new_df['number_of_incomplete_segments']), max(new_df['number_of_returned_segments']),
                             max(new_df['number_of_completed_segments']))])
)

fig = go.Figure(data=[trace], layout=layout)



app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Square Root Slider Graph'),

    dcc.Graph(id='slider-graph', figure={'data': [fig] }, animate=True, style={"backgroundColor": "#1a2d46", 'color': '#ffffff'},
              ),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='demo-dropdown',
                 options=[
                     {'label': 'Daily', 'value': 'daily'},
                     {'label': 'Weekly', 'value': 'weekly'},
                     {'label': 'Monthly', 'value': 'monthly'}
                 ],
                 value='weekly'),
])
```

I dont know why the graph object not supported in dash plotly

any one have an idea ?

many thanks

Answer (score 3):

The value of the `figure` attribute in `dcc.Graph` should be that returned by `go.Figure`. ie

```
dcc.Graph(figure=fig)
```

Comment: would it be the same returning a `go.Figure` in a callback?  in my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64400951/plotly-dash-dcc-dropdown-not-initiating-calback-after-being-placed-inside-boostr

Comment: Yep. If your callback is returning a single Plotly figure object, then the callback's `Output`, should be the `figure` property of a `dcc.Graph` component.

Answer (score 0):

You are making syntax mistake. You should assign your `fig` object to `figure`.

```
dcc.Graph(
        id='slider-graph',
        figure=fig
    )
```